# unknown tikz picture error

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-pic

I really don't know what the problem is but for some reason, this piece of codes works only once. I have it in an active document and it works fine, but now when I try to copy and paste it for a second time it doesn't work - it's exactly the same as the other one which works fine. I even created a new file with the same preamble and it doesn't work anymore - it really doesn't make sense. It seems to exclusively be a problem with the sections marked "%angle". It's frustrating because my assigment is due today and I'm really short for time. Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={bf}}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf}}


\setlength{\mathindent}{0.5in}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{}
\cfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}

%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\newcommand\Mydiv[2]{%
\strut#1\kern.25em\smash{\raise.3ex\hbox{\big)}}\mkern-8mu
        \overline{\enspace\strut#2}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][c]{\hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols #1}}
\makeatother

\parindent 0ex

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


            \begin{tikzpicture}[
                            force/.style={>=latex,draw=black,fill=black},
                            axis/.style={densely dashed,gray,font=\small},
                            M/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=lightgray,minimum size=0.01cm,thin},
]
                            \matrix[column sep=2.5cm] {

                                &
                                % Free body diagram of M1
                                \begin{scope}[rotate=0]
                                    \node[M,transform shape] (M) {};
                                        % Draw axes and help lines
                                            {[axis, -]
                                            \draw (1.5,-1.5) -- (M)


                                                                                        {};
                                % angles
                                \draw[solid,shorten, >=0.5pt] (-45:\arcr)
                                        arc(-45:-90:0.5cm);
                                        \node at (0.28,-0.65) {$\alpha$};


                                 }

                                    % Forces
                                    {[force,->, very thick]
                                        \draw (M) -- ++ (-1.5, 1.5) node[above] {$\textbf{N}_1$};
                                        \draw (M) -- ++ (1.5,1.5) node[above] {$\textbf{T}_1$};
                                        \draw node[right] {$\hspace{0.05in}m_1$};
                                        \draw (M) -- ++ (0,-1.5) node[below] {$\textbf{W}_1$};}

                                \end{scope}

                                &
                                % Free body diagram of M2
                                \begin{scope}[rotate=0]
                                    \node[M,transform shape] (M) {};
                                        % Draw axes and help lines
                                            {[axis, -]
                                            \draw (1.5,-1.5) -- (M)


                                                                                        {};
                                % angles
                                \draw[solid,shorten >=0.5pt] (-45:\arcr)
                                        arc(-45:-90:0.5cm);
                                        \node at (0.28,-0.65) {$\alpha$};


                                 }

                                    % Forces
                                    {[force,->, very thick]
                                        \draw (M) -- ++ (-1.5, 1.5) node[above] {$\textbf{N}_2$};
                                        \draw (M) -- ++ (-1.5,-1.5) node[above left] {$\textbf{T}_2$};
                                        \draw (M) -- ++ (1.5,1.5) node[above left] {\textbf{F}};                                        

                                        \draw node[right] {$\hspace{0.05in}m_2$};
                                        \draw (M) -- ++ (0,-1.5) node[below] {$\textbf{W}_2$};}

                                \end{scope}

\\
};
                        \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

The errors I get are "! Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind '0.5pt'." etc. If I remove the sections where the arc is drawn then the errors dissappear. I appreciate any help but I really don't know much about LaTeX.

**Edit**: this is what it looks like, normally

[image: diagram]

Comment: Welcome! The first error comes from the comma in `shorten, >=0.5pt`, which should be `shorten >=0.5pt`. But if one fixes that, the next problem is that `\arcr` is not defined. What is that supposed to be?

Comment: I'll make that change right now and update you, thank you

Comment: If I add `\def\arcr{0.5cm}` before the line that macro gets used, the code runs through. An arguably easier way of drawing these angle arcs is to use the `angles` library.

Comment: the \arcr part is supposed to be the starting pointing of the angle/arc. So, it starts from -45 degrees and then ends at -90 degrees. I'm gonna post a picture using the same code and it working fine in another document just to try to help

Comment: omg it worked! thank you so much! I'm super grateful for your help! Do you have any idea why it would work normally in another document but not in this one?

Comment: Probably in the other document `\def\arcr{0.5cm}` can be found somewhere before the `tikzpicture` but hard to say with 100% certainty without seeing the document.

Comment: You were right! For some reason I missed that one out D: do i need to add that line before every tikz picture that's, for example, identical to the one I posted? If you're able to add a very short, basic answer to this post I can mark it as the answer for some extra rep for you :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposal to draw the angles with arguably less pitfalls. Use the `angles` library, which is made for that. I would also draw the vectors first, then you can use them to define the angles.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,scopes,quotes}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0.5in}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{}
\cfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}

%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\newcommand\Mydiv[2]{%
\strut#1\kern.25em\smash{\raise.3ex\hbox{\big)}}\mkern-8mu
        \overline{\enspace\strut#2}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][c]{\hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols #1}}
\makeatother

\parindent 0ex

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    force/.style={>=latex,draw=black,fill=black},
    axis/.style={densely dashed,gray,font=\small},
    M/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=lightgray,minimum size=0.01cm,thin},
]                           \def\arcr{0.5cm}
\matrix[column sep=2.5cm] {
        % Free body diagram of M1
  \begin{scope}[rotate=0]
      \node[M,transform shape] (M) {};
          % Draw axes and help lines
      % Forces
      {[force,->, very thick]
          \draw (M) -- ++ (-1.5, 1.5) node[above] {$\mathbf{N}_1$};
          \draw (M) -- ++ (1.5,1.5) node[above] {$\mathbf{T}_1$};
          \draw node[right] {$\hspace{0.05in}m_1$};
          \draw (M) -- ++ (0,-1.5) node[below] (W1) {$\mathbf{W}_1$};}
      {[axis, -]
              \draw (1.5,-1.5) coordinate (A) -- (M);
               % angles
              \pic [draw,solid,->,angle radius=0.5cm,"$\alpha$",
                angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = W1--M--A}; 
            }

  \end{scope}
  &
  % Free body diagram of M2
  \begin{scope}[rotate=0]
      \node[M,transform shape] (M) {};
          % Forces
          {[force,->, very thick]
              \draw (M) -- ++ (-1.5, 1.5) node[above] {$\mathbf{N}_2$};
              \draw (M) -- ++ (-1.5,-1.5) node[above left] {$\mathbf{T}_2$};
              \draw (M) -- ++ (1.5,1.5) node[above left] {$\mathbf{F}$};                                        
              \draw node[right=0.05in] {$m_2$};
              \draw (M) -- ++ (0,-1.5) node[below] (W2) {$\mathbf{W}_2$};}
          % Draw axes and help lines
              {[axis, -]
              \draw (1.5,-1.5) coordinate (A') -- (M);
              \pic [draw,solid,->,angle radius=0.5cm,"$\alpha$",
                angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = W2--M--A}; 
               }
  \end{scope}
\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Some forces.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have dropped the styles that are not relevant for the picture. However, if you put this code in your document, make sure you load the libraries used here with

```
\usetikzlibrary{angles,scopes,quotes}
```

Note also that `\textbf` is not designed for math mode, so I changed it to `\mathbf` (but I'd prefer `\boldsymbol` yet that is a matter of taste).